# What does "status" in <s:iterator> do?

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator

I am using the following command to display values from 'userList'

```
<s:iterator value="userList" status="rowStatus">
  <tr class="even"> 
    <td><s:property value="tweet_id" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="message" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="created" /></td>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

What is the use of `status="rowStatus"` in this command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, none.

When iterating, the current object is pushed on top of the Value Stack. This means you can access it by simply using its name (along with [the many other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516627/1654265)).

You can use this value as you wish for the `value` attribute.

But if (in a case different from your, but that you will certainly encounter soon) you need to put this value in a form field **that will be submitted back to an(other) Action**, targeting a `List<YourObject>` attribute, then you need to use IteratorStatus to mount the correct `name` attribute. For example:

SourceAction

```
private List<User> sourceUserList;
```

TargetAction

```
private List<User> updatedUserList;
```

JSP

```
<s:form action="targetAction">
  <s:iterator value="sourceUserList" status="rowStatus">

    <s:hidden name="updatedUserList[%{#rowStatus.index}].id" value="id"/>
    <s:property value="id" />

    <s:textfield name="updatedUserList[%{#rowStatus.index}].name" value="name" />
    <s:textfield name="updatedUserList[%{#rowStatus.index}].age"  value="age"  />

  </s:iterator>
  <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

Got it ?

Comment: what if we dont know that  name and age are there? How can we show all of those?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking :/

Comment: I am asking to do this dynamically.  You hard coded .age and .name.

Comment: [You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15452512/1654265)

Answer (score 7):

From [docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html).

> The iterator tag can export an IteratorStatus object so that one can
>   get information about the status of the iteration, such as:
>
> ```
> index: current iteration index, starts on 0 and increments in one on every iteration
> count: iterations so far, starts on 1. count is always index + 1
> first: true if index == 0
> even: true if (index + 1) % 2 == 0
> last: true if current iteration is the last iteration
> odd: true if (index + 1) % 2 == 1
> ```

Example

```
   <s:iterator status="rowStatus" value='{0, 1}'>
      Index: <s:property value="%{#rowStatus.index}" /> <br />
      Count: <s:property value="%{#rowStatus.count}" /> <br />  
   </s:iterator>
```

will print

```
  Index: 0
  Count: 1
  Index: 1
  Count: 2
```

In your userList

```
userList count = 1 to userList.size();
userList index = 0 to userList.size() - 1;
```